# ¿Cómo comprobar si una hora está entre otras dos?

Tags: php, condiciones, horas

Estoy comprobando si un negocio está abierto cuando uno entra al sitio con el siguiente código pero sí el negocio abre y cierra en un rango mayor a 12 horas no actúa como debería.

```
if ($hour > strtotime($lunes_open_hour) && $hour < strtotime($lunes_close_hour)) {
    $open_now = true;
} 
else {
    $open_now = false;
}

//$lunes_open_hour = 8:00;
//$lunes_close_hour = 21::00; 
// $open = true;

//$lunes_open_hour = 13:00;
//$lunes_close_hour = 2::00; 
// $open = false;  Aquí debería dar true
```

¿Qué puedo hacer? Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué es `$hour` en tu código?

Comment: ¿Y cómo se controlan las horas que caen al día siguiente? Por ejemplo, cuando comparas una hora de términos después de la medianoche, esa hora estaría cayendo en el siguiente día. Explica cómo se deben tratar estos casos en tu contexto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te aconsejo que uses la clase `DateTime` o similares cuando vayas a trabajar con fechas/horas en PHP. Es muy flexible, potente y facilita en muchos casos tareas complicadas.

Dado que en ciertos casos la hora final puede entrar en una fecha que sería el día siguiente, tienes que determinar eso, para aumentar el objeto que representaría a la hora actual y poder comparar sin problemas.

Advierto que el código no es mío, lo he tomado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27134087/5587982) de SO en inglés, modificando algunas cosas, como es crear la hora actual dentro de la misma función.

```
function isBetween($from, $to) {
    $now = DateTime::createFromFormat('!H:i', date('H:i'));
    $f = DateTime::createFromFormat('!H:i', $from);
    $t = DateTime::createFromFormat('!H:i', $to);
    /*
        Determina si $to caería al día siguiente
        en cuyo caso aumentaremos un día al objeto 
        que representa a la hora final
    */
    if ($f > $t) $t->modify('+1 day');
    return ($f <= $now && $now <= $t) || ($f <= $now->modify('+1 day') && $now <= $t);
}
```

Vamos a hacer las pruebas (por cierto, vigila de no poner `::` en las horas):

```
$lunes_open_hour = "8:00";
$lunes_close_hour = "21:00"; 
var_dump(isBetween($lunes_open_hour,$lunes_close_hour));


$lunes_open_hour = "13:00";
$lunes_close_hour = "2:00"; 
var_dump(isBetween($lunes_open_hour,$lunes_close_hour));
```

**Salida:**

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

[**<kbd>`VER DEMO EN REXTESTER`</kbd>**](https://rextester.com/LUN33638)

Answer (score 0):

Basado en el código que muestras, y como veo que comparas `$hour` con un `strtotime` supongo que `$hour` será la hora actual, por lo tanto lo podrías hacer así:

```
<?php

$hour = strtotime("now"); //Esta es mi suposición

// Your code here!
$lunes_open_hour = "13:00";
$lunes_close_hour = "02:00";

$openTime = strtotime($lunes_open_hour);
$closeTime = strtotime($lunes_close_hour);

if($closeTime < $openTime){ //Si esto es true, es porque la hora de cierre es del día siguiente, no del mismo día, entonces le sumas 24 horas
    $closeTime += 86400; //Le sumas 24 horas (expresado en segundos)
}    

if ($hour >= $openTime && $hour <= $closeTime) {
    $open_now = true;
} else {
    $open_now = false;
}

var_dump($open_now); //Debug para ver el resultado
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada tu evaluacion es ambigua; o le faltan detalles, Tienes dos escenarios:

***1. las horas que estan dentro de un dia:***

*Los input:*

```
8:00:00 //entrada
12:00:00 //hora Actual
21:00:00 //hora de salida
```

*Script php:*

```php
$entrada = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i','8:00');
$actual = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i','12:00');
$salida = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i','21:00');

$open_now = ($entrada < $actual && $actual < $salida)? true : false;

if($open_now){
    echo 'Abierto';
}else{
    echo 'Cerrado';
}
```

*output:*

```
Abierto
```

***2. las horas que estan dentro de dos dias:*** 
***nota:*** Para este escenario no te va a servir la opcion 1.

*Los input:*

```
2022-12-12 8:00:00
2022-12-11 12:00:00
2022-12-12 21:00:00
```

*Script php:*

```php
<?php
$entrada = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i','2022-12-12 8:00');
$actual = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i','2022-12-11 12:00');
$salida = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i','2022-12-12 21:00');

$open_now = ($entrada < $actual && $actual < $salida)? true : false;

if($open_now){
    echo 'Abierto';
}else{
    echo 'Cerrado';
}
```

*output:*

```
Cerrado
```

Como podras ver en el escenario 1 funciona perfectamente; pero que pasa cuando tenemos dias diferente entonces ya todo cambia; espero que dependiendo de tu necesidades puedas adaptar mis script.

***Documentacion:***

[DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) 
[Operadores Ternarios](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

***Implementacion:***

```
<?php
function isWorkingHours(string $entrada, string $actual, $salida)
{
    $entrada_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $entrada);
    $actual_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $actual);
    $salida_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $salida);
    return ($entrada_dt < $actual_dt && $actual_dt < $salida_dt);
}

if( isWorkingHours('2022-12-12 8:00','2022-12-11 12:00','2022-12-12 21:00') ){
    echo 'Abierto';
} else {
    echo 'Cerrado';
}
```